# Start spark from a scala shell

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How can I start spark from an sbt shell. I don't want to use the spark-shell command. I would like to use spark and use the objects in my sbt project.

Comment: Scala shell or sbt shell?

Comment: You can use ammonite and load libraries in it.

Comment: https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org https://scala-cli.virtuslab.org/spark/